# HTCondor gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, condor

When I use HTCondor to submit a shell script which contains something like `gcc code.c -o code.o`, the error file says that `error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory`.
However, when I just type `gcc code.c -o code.o` in the shell on the execute machine, everything works fine.
Anyone knows the reason? I am working on ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be environment variables defined in the HTCondor environment that set gcc off to search for `cc1` (which is an internal compiler executable) in the wrong place, such as `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` and `COMPILER_PATH`, or, gcc may be missing from the `PATH` in HTCondor (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) regarding influential GCC env. variables).

I would suggest the following troubleshooting procedure:

- In the normal shell, check the location of gcc (`which gcc`).
- Make sure that the folder where gcc is located is a part of the `PATH` in HTCondor - or append it to the begining of that `PATH` (`export PATH=/path/to/gcc:$PATH`).
- Make sure that variables `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` and `COMPILER_PATH` are not set in the HTCondor environment.
- If the above doesn't work, you could try the other way around and set `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` to the location of gcc in the HTCondor script.

**Edit:**

As per your findings, adding the `getenv = true` command to `condor_submit` [(doc)](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/condor_submit.html) resolves the issue:

> **getenv = (True | False)**
>   If getenv is set to True, then condor_submit will copy all of the user's current shell environment variables at the time of job submission into the job ClassAd. The job will therefore execute with the same set of environment variables that the user had at submit time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I add `getenv = true` in my submit file and that works.

Comment: @AlanRivers simple :-) Glad to help

Comment: @AlanRivers I updated my answer according to your findings, for completing it and hopefully helping future visitors - please consider accepting it, if it seems OK